# Entity Framework DbContext is initialized with wrong constructor

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

In my ASP.NET Core Web API, I add the `DbContext` to services:

```
 services.AddDbContext<OpContext>(options =>  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DatabaseConnectionString"]));
```

The problem is that my dbcontext as three constructors:

```
 public partial class UppContext : DbContext
 {
    public UppContext() : base()
    { }

    public UppContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options) 
    { }

    public UppContext(IIdentificationService idService) : base()
    {
        _idService = idService;
    }
```

And `OpContext` inherits from the above:

```
public partial class OpContext : UppContext
{
    public OpContext() : base() { }
    public OpContext(IIdentificationService idService) : base(idService) { }

    public OpContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options)   { }
}
```

And instead of calling the one with options, it always calls the parameterless constructor. Therefore my connection does not work.

This is where I inject it in the controller :

```
  public RequestController(OpContext dbContext)
    {
        cxt = dbContext;
        persistenceManager = new OpPersistenceManager(dbContext);
    }
```

This is the actual exception:

[image]

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=No
> database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider
> can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or
> by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If
> AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
> accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and
> passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore   StackTrace:    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.Initialize(IServiceProvider
> scopedProvider, IDbContextOptions contextOptions, DbContext context)
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ChangeTracker()    at
> Breeze.Persistence.EFCore.EFPersistenceManager`1..ctor(T context)
> at Op.Authors.Api.Breeze.OpPersistenceManager..ctor(OpContext
> dbContext) in
> C:\dev\UPP\Source\Op\Op.Authors.Api\Breeze\OpPersistenceManager.cs:line
> 8    at Op.Authors.Api.Controllers.RequestController..ctor(OpContext
> dbContext) in
> C:\dev\UPP\Source\Op\Op.Authors.Api\Controllers\RequestController.cs:line
> 21    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

Am I missing something?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217457/discussion-on-question-by-sam-entity-framework-dbcontext-is-initialized-with-wro).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I reproduced your code, but with one level of inheritance.

Changing

```cs
public OpContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options)   { }
```

to

```cs
public OpContext(DbContextOptions<OpContext> options) : base(options)   { }
```

resolved the issue for me.

Notice the type argument for DbContextOptions.

Comment: that's nice :) Thanks edo.n. I'll mark this as the answer.